# Notepad++ add numeric value to each repeated scripts

Tags: powershell, notepad++

I have a txt file with digits only at each line,

```
1234  
2345  
3456  
4567
```

I would like to put this each line to values in powershell but over 1000 times.

```
$id = "1234"
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]
$i = $l.GetItemById($id)

$id = "2345"
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]
$i = $l.GetItemById($id)

$id = "3456"
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]
$i = $l.GetItemById($id)
```

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this using Notepad++ or anything? thank you,

Comment: Also, what do you mean by over 1000 times?

Comment: i have 1000 + numbers in a txt file that I removed all other text based values. Just need those event IDs inserted to looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to loop through each number in your source file and perform the same action. Use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

```
gc "C:\foo.txt" | % {

    $id = $_
    $w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
    $l = $w.Lists[$listName]
    $i = $l.GetItemById($id)

}
```

Alternatively, you could record a macro in Notepad++ to format your file.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+`
- Replace with: `$id = "$0"\n$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb\n$l = $w.Lists[$listName]\n$i = $l.GetItemById\($id\)\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d+     : 1 or more digits
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0  means whole match, ie. the number

$id = "$0"  : first line
\n          : line break, you could use \r\n
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb  : second line
\n          : line break, you could use \r\n
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]    : third line
\n          : line break, you could use \r\n
$i = $l.GetItemById\($id\)  : fourth line, parenthesis have to be escaped in Npp
\n          : line break, you could use \r\n
```

**Result for given example:**

```
$id = "1234"
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]
$i = $l.GetItemById($id)

$id = "2345"
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]
$i = $l.GetItemById($id)

$id = "3456"
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]
$i = $l.GetItemById($id)

$id = "4567"
$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]
$i = $l.GetItemById($id)
```

Comment: You write $1 in your regex, and $0 in your explaination, also you don't add (..) for groups, so I bet you have made a typo somewhere in there.. :) other than that, this is the best method.

Comment: @LPChip: You're right, it was a typo.

Comment: @JayYoo: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: I thought so. +1 from me after you fixed it. Now this is definitely the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing but the numbers in the file, you can do a find and replace using the end of line characters and replacing them with everything you need added.  Like so:

**Find**

```
\r\n
```

**Replace**

```
"\r\n$w = Get-SPWeb $urlWeb\r\n$l = $w.Lists[$listName]\r\n$i = $l.GetItemById($id)\r\n\r\n$id = "
```

This will need a little manual clean up on the first and last numbers, but otherwise it's just a single Replace All step.  Make sure you have your Find and Replace Search Mode set to **Extended**.